# Prometheus exceeded maximum resolution of 11,000 points or empty result

Tags: postman, prometheus, grafana, metrics, endpoint

I'm currently struggling with getting empty results from requests to my Prometheus endpoint.

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "data": {
        "resultType": "matrix",
        "result": []
    }
}
```

If I check out the data on grafana for this stack/instance over a 7 day period, I can see there's metrics for this stack, but the metrics were only coming through for ~15 minutes (until the stack was destroyed). That's all fine with me, I'd like to get metrics during that time frame it was alive..

[Grafana 7day interval](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g1Llb.png)

If we take a look at here in grafana, values start coming through when I specify a short enough interval of time.

[Grafana smaller time interval](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tzyrk.png)

Great, now all I want to do is get that value back from prometheus with a postman request.

Since I had troubles with using Prometheus' "query" request, I started trying to use "query_range" so I could specify a time to start/stop. I was assuming that if I didn't specify a time, I would be in the same situation as with Grafana before showing the graph on a large time interval but no values would appear.

After sending the request on a small step count, I get back

```
exceeded maximum resolution of 11,000 points per timeseries. Try decreasing the query resolution (?step=XX)
```

[postman request small step interval](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZEJ0.png)

This helps me to believe that **i am** getting metrics back, but just too many for prometheus to send over.

So, I increase the step interval (I've tried different combinations of seconds/minutes) and it always gives back the following -

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "data": {
        "resultType": "matrix",
        "result": []
    }
}
```

[Postman request valid step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JxIJe.png)

I can't seem to get around this issue of getting back an empty result set. Any ideas on why this resultset might be coming back as empty? I've tried getting an average by wrapping the query in "avg()" but it also gives back an empty result.

Tried sending a postman request to get prometheus metrics but I got back an empty value or that it exceeded maximum resolution of 11,000 points per timeseries.

Comment: Although I understand why you've included screenshots, it would be helpful to include the data from the screenshots in order to help people answer your question. According to [EpochConverter](https://www.epochconverter.com/), start 1675125296974 is 31-Jan-2023 0:34:56.974 GMT and end 1675125312106 is 31-Jan-2023 0:35:12.106 but eyeballing your Grafana graph (and without knowing its timezone), suggests that the stack exists on 30-Jan-2023.... So, you're looking in the timeframe hence the empty result.

Comment: The window is also only 15 seconds which likely doesn't include (m)any measurements.

Comment: @DazWilkin I'm taking a look in Grafana and the stack was alive from 12:12 pm. to 12:33p.m. and pulling straight from the query inspector I get the following values:
Start: 1675105923950
End: 1675107193600
I attempted to run a new query with those start/end and it's still giving back an empty set

Comment: (12:12 p.m. is 1675105923950 in my time zone) 
@DazWilkin where is the "15 second window" you're referring to?

Comment: Final Comment: It's because the UNIX timestamp was too long. See my comment for additional info.

Answer (score 0):

Just found out the solution. This is really dumb but it seems like the Prometheus endpoint doesn't like it when you pass in too long of a UNIX timestamp.

I realized this by troubleshooting the following:

1675106064891 - did not work

1675106103 - did work

My Grafana metrics start getting published around Mon Jan 30 2023 19:11:45 GMT+0000 which is **before** both of those unix timestamps. So, what was the difference? Well, I tried adding more values onto the UNIX timestamp that **did** work and voila, I stopped getting metric values back.

Hope this response saves you some time if you encounter the same error. I wish Prometheus would give some context on why that value is empty or something.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, there are so many data between start and end time.
When I reduce the time period, then it works fine.
(I tested this query in the postman and connected server using windows putty)

For example, when I run this query to get data between 2023-10-02 and 2023-10-03, it occurs error.
`http://localhost:9090/api/v1/query_range?query=luke_field_numDocs{cluster_name="order-services-primary2", collection="orders_prod_new", shard="shard35", replica="replica_n277", name="AUTH_ATTEMPT_FAIL"}&start=2023-10-02T00:00:00.000Z&end=2023-10-03T10:00:00.000Z&step=5s`

Result is here

```
{
    "status": "error",
    "errorType": "bad_data",
    "error": "exceeded maximum resolution of 11,000 points per timeseries. Try decreasing the query resolution (?step=XX)"
}
```

After changing to get data inside Oct 2 like following , it works.

```
http://localhost:9090/api/v1/query_range?query=luke_field_numDocs{cluster_name="order-services-primary2", collection="orders_prod_new", shard="shard35", replica="replica_n277", name="AUTH_ATTEMPT_FAIL"}&start=2023-10-02T00:00:00.000Z&end=2023-10-02T10:00:00.000Z&step=5s
```

Then result:

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "data": {
        "resultType": "matrix",
        "result": [
            {
                "metric": {
                    "__name__": "luke_field_numDocs",
                    "az": "southcentralus",
                    "cluster_name": "order-services-primary2",
                    "collection": "orders_prod_new",
                    "collector_version": "0.8",
                    "datacenter": "southcentralus",
                    "instance": "localhost:8000",
                    "job": "search-insights",
                    "name": "AUTH_ATTEMPT_FAIL",
                    "replica": "replica_n277",
                    "shard": "shard35",
                    "timestamp": "1696219802",
                    "type": "strings",
                    "url": "../data/searchinsights-2023_09_12-18_46_07_15388/solr/"
                },
                "values": [
                    [
                        1696219845,
                        "2"
                    ],
                    [
                        1696219850,
                        "2"
                    ],
                    [
                        1696219855,
                        "2"
                    ]
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Here is screenshot in the postman.
https://prnt.sc/t9CYqfWeB4IL
[image]

Hope this gives help to solve your issues.